# loyality program database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have an ecommerce shop and I'm going to make a loyality program. After each purchase, user recieve bonuses to his own account.

I have:

1. `users` table
2. `orders` table

I need to understand, how to do it correctly. My thoughts:

1. Create a table user_bonuses (`user_id`, `order_id`, `bonuses`)
2. Create a new column on `users` table - `bonuses`
3. Create a new column on `orders` - `bonuses`

Answer (score 1):

**First**: There is a relationship between `users` and `orders`. Then you have `users` P.K as F.K in the `orders`. So you can set the `bonuses` to `orders`. If you set it the `users`, you can not find this question: In which `orders` the user get the bonuses. So, with setting the `bonuses` to `orders`, you save more information.

However, you can use another column in `users` to hold the sum of all `users`'s bonuses. There is no need to this column in more designs. But, it's related the number of records of `orders`.

**Second**: getting the `bonuses` as a column or a table. 
It's related to some conditions:

1. data (columns) of `bonuses`. If you have a lot of columns in `bonuses`, it's better to get a new table to it and (based on my first point) related it to `orders`.
2. If there is a few columns in `bonuses` like `amount` and `created_date`, it is better to hold them as columns in `orders`.
3. But, you can use a new table like `bonuses_types` and save all common and base information of all `bonuses` in it. Then based on 1 or 2, you can use `bonuses` as a table or columns.